# Javascript: Transfer Elements td's to td's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablelayout

I know my title is quite confusing but let me explain.

Basically I want to manipulate a table to add and insert tr's and td's anytime because that is what I decided to do for my layout.It's like this:

On the first wave, let's say window = 1, the layout should simply shows one window:

```
     []
     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
     </tr>
```

Second wave, window = 2:

```
     [] []
     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
     </tr>
```

Third wave, windows = 3:

```
     []
     []
     []
     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
     </tr>
```

fourth wave, windows = 4:

```
     [] []
     [] []

     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
     </tr>
```

Those brackets would be like a div inside a td. It does not matter on what is inside the div for as long as those windows are formatted that way.

I already got till second wave, but unable to proceed at window3. What I got is li

```
     []
     [] []

     <tr>
              <td><div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
              <td><div></td>
              <td><div></td>
     </tr>
```

Which is not suppose to be. How do I do it like the expected result as stated before in javascript? there will be like a trigger it to transform each wave. Any ideas? kindly help. Thanks

Comment: First. Don't use tables for this.

Comment: Second. Here's what I get from your description: Start with one box. Add one box on each 'wave'. When total number of boxes is odd, arrange in a single column. When total number of boxes is even, arrange in two columns. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use divs instead of tables. Start with a single container div that will hold all the others.

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

On each iteration, add a child and change the class of the container to reflect having an odd or even number of children.

first:

```
<div class="container odd">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

second:

```
<div class="container even">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

third:

```
<div class="container odd">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

and so on.

Then just write some css to put `.odd` in one column and `.even` in two.

Comment: What happens if I reach the 3rd iteration comming from the 2nd? And then coming from the third going to fourth how do I template? Just let the CSS do the templating? is that what your saying?

Comment: I'm saying that you only need to do two things per iteration: 1) add a div. 2) set the odd/even class on the parent div. In your css, you will have rules for .odd and rules for .even which will automatically go into effect based on the class change. These rules should define the layout. I'm leaving that part up to you but it should not be difficult.

Comment: Yep, it worked perfectly. This is much better than using the table layout. Thanks a lot.